# Frequently getting Read timed out in SQL Server 2008 Hibernate 4.1

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, amazon-web-services

We are facing one strange issue with sql server 2008r2 and hibernate. Frequently getting read timeout error from the database, here is the error details:

```
    10:02:11,368 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
    10:02:11,368 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) Read timed out
    10:02:11,368 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Read timed out10:02:11,368 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36)  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)10:02:11,368 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36)    
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)10:02:11,368 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36)   
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)10:02:11,368 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36)   
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)10:02:11,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36)   
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)10:02:11,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) 




... 131 more10:02:11,727 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    10:02:11,727 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) The connection is closed.
    10:02:11,727 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/CastrolCubedUnit].[spring]] (http-/55.2.0.180:443-36) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

Few More information if its related:

1. We are using C3P0 connection pooling with hibernate. And configured
   connection testing as well. We have checked the DB with(in the time
   of exception occurring) exec sp_lock command DB is only holding S or
   IS lock
2. We are not getting this in local environment in local its running
       fine
3. Application is hosted in Amazon aws with two application server and
       one load balancer where the issue persist.

We are stuck into this help is much appreciated.

Comment: For each query you are getting this?

Comment: can you able to telnet to DB server?

Comment: Not for each query but once start getting this error we are getting this very frequently. And yes telnet is working fine.

Comment: What is your time_Out setting in c3p0 settings file? and is there any query which is taking time more then time_out setting

Comment: Dont think so .. here is our hiberate settings and c3p0 settings

Comment: Dont think so .. here is our hibernate settings and c3p0 settings

<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>


==========================
C3p0 Properties :
===========================
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=1000
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=1

Comment: @testwork I don't think its problem related to c3p0 settings. Its problem related to servers. But to be sure can you try to increase timeout time some more. Or you can also check DB server for slow quries

Comment: Do you have guess on what kind of server issue that might happen and causing this ? Also please suggest how do I check the slow queries.

Comment: Server issues like DB server is not responding or busy in executing some long query and web server request timeout is over or it may happen telnet is not working which u have checked or As you said your application is behind LB so please check LB is not blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQl server keeps statistical information about all queries. table `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` having the statistics about each query but before that I suggest you to run DBCC command which  restarts logging of the query running time and some cache clear work is done.

DNDC Command `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

And following is the query to find long query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
t.TEXT QueryName,
s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime,
ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime,
s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
ISNULL(s.execution_count / DATEDIFF(s, s.creation_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
ORDER BY
s.max_elapsed_time DESC
GO
```

You can go through [This Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx) for optimizing query.